# Qt application not a valid 32bit application

Tags: qt

I made a simple Qt application. Everything is working well on mt PC. I use Windows 7 SP1 and Qt Creator for building and debugging. When I try to run my program on Win XP I get the error "Not a valid 32 application". I had the same problem when I was making applications with Visual Studio 2012. However I fixed that problem with Visual Studio. In Tools -> Options I made it wo be compiling for Win XP. And everything was working on my PC and on the PC with XP. But I can't find such option in Qt Creator. How can I run my application on Windows XP?

Comment: Wild guess: You probably compiled 64-bit code. Try to find an option for this (architecture should be i386 or x86 and not amd64 or x86_64)

Comment: Can't find such option. But my Windows 7 on which I made tha app is also 32-bit and everything is working.

Comment: what is your home setup? Is it Qt creator with SDK??

Comment: Umm how can I check that? I don't remember downloading anything with SDK in it's name

Answer (score 0):

Qt-Creator is only IDE, it uses compiler you tell it to use (I'm assuming it would be VS2012 in your case).

You can check compiler/linker flags in your other VS2012 solution that make a difference (what changes as you set "option compiling for Win XP" when you look to command line input to compiler/linker), and set same flags in your Qt .pro file.

You can see actual input to compiler/linker by going to project properties->C/C++->Command line and Linker->Commnd line respectively in your VS2012 project.

You can set compiler/linker flags in qt using

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=
```

and

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=
```

in qt .pro file respectively.

Comment: I tried but I can't find that option there. This is what I did on VS2012 http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/linking-applications-using-visual-studio-2012-to-run-on-windows-xp But there is no option like that in Qt Creator

Comment: Please see edit. I doubt there would be a single check-box option as qt-creator as it is cross platform and is not focused on vs2012, but you surely can configure proper settings manually.

Comment: where should I write that?

Comment: And what? If I write this there I will be able to run it ot Win XP?

Comment: You need to figure out which compiler and linker flags make a difference, and pass that flags through qt make file. I explained you how to figure that out in the answer above. You need some work to do to figure out which flags, if you "write this there" it of course won't work.